# How to logout from SAML authentication?

Tags: flutter, dart, single-sign-on, saml, single-sign-out

I am using a SAML link for authentication.

and here is my code implementation:

```
class LoginWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginWebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginWebView> createState() => _LoginWebViewState();
}

class _LoginWebViewState extends State<LoginWebView> {
  final tokenManager = TokenManager();
  InAppWebViewController? inAppWebViewController;
  bool isShowingError = false;
  late var url;
  var initialUrl =
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=858410514048&forceauthn=false";

  //late WebViewController controller;
  String? token;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(initialUrl)),
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                inAppWebViewController = controller;
              },
              onProgressChanged: onWebViewProgressChanged,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I am unable to logout the user.

**Can anyone please tell me how to logout from SAML based authentication?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps to logout user

1. When a user clicks the logout button, your app should send a **SAML
   Logout Request** to the **IdP**. This request tells the **IdP** that the user
   wants to log out.
2. Now IdP will give you response based on your request, handle it.
3. Now verify its **authenticity**.
4. after successful verification, clear **local session** of user.
5. Now **redirect** user to your further screen.

**here is sample code.**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void initiateSamlLogout() async {
  // 1. Send Logout Request to IdP
  final idpLogoutUrl = 'https://idp.example.com/logout'; // Replace with your IdP's logout URL
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(idpLogoutUrl));

  // 2. Handle Logout Response
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // 3. Invalidate the Local Session
    // Clear user session data, tokens, etc.

    // 4. Redirect or Notify the User
    // Redirect or show a confirmation message.
  } else {
    // Handle error in receiving Logout Response.
  }
}
```

Comment: But, how can I get this `idpLogoutUrl`, could you please help me further?

Comment: You can configure logout url on your Google Workspace admin console, inside SAML apps settings.

Comment: Hi, do we have any kind of documentation or other of generating this `idpLogoutUrl`, so that I can follow that and create that URL on the **Google Workspace admin console**? I will be grateful to you for this.